# Using sub-query column in where clause

Tags: postgresql

This question has been asked several times and even answered as well but it's not helpful to me, that's why I am posting it again. I have this query:

```
select u.*,l.*, 
(
    select count(cr.id) 
    from cloud_recordings cr 
    left join cameras c 
        on c.owner_id=u.id 
    where c.id=cr.camera_id
) valid_licence
from users u 
left join licences l 
    on l.user_id=u.id;
```

It works fine, but when I put a where clause at the end:

```
select u.*,l.*, 
(
    select count(cr.id) 
    from cloud_recordings cr 
    left join cameras c 
        on c.owner_id=u.id 
    where c.id=cr.camera_id
) valid_licence
from users u 
left join licences l 
    on l.user_id=u.id
where valid_licence > 0;
```

It simply gave me an error:

> ERROR:  column "valid_licence" does not exist
>   LINE 4: left join licences l on l.user_id=u.id where valid_licence >..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't reference an alias on the same "level" where it was defined. You need to wrap your base query into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select u.*,
         l.*, 
         (select count(cr.id) from cloud_recordings cr left join cameras c on c.owner_id=u.id where c.id=cr.camera_id) valid_licence
  from users u 
    left join licences l on l.user_id=u.id 
) t
where valid_licence > 0;
```

Comment: +1. Pretty sure they'll get some other error though (due to the ORMish sillymess of having an `id` in every table ;)

Answer (score 1):

To understand this error you need to understand that the SELECT is actually being parsed last. At the time WHERE is being parsed the SELECT statement hasn't been run and so valid_license has not been set up as an alias/computation.

Discussed more here:
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/

or google Logical Query Processing